# replacing the value of an element in an array without creating a new array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm learning Ruby and have been practicing by solving problems on Codewars and Leetcode. I've come across this problem in Leetcode where it is asking me to, given an array and a value, modify the array in place by removing an occurrence of the value given in the array. Pretty simple! I was able to solve it- but, this curious thing happened and I don't know why!
Here's my code:

```
def remove_element(nums, val)
  nums.each_with_index do |num, index|
      if num == val
          nums[index] = nil
      end
  end
    nums.compact!
    nums.length
end
```

You can see here that on line 4 I've written "nums[index] = nil", and this worked just fine for me. However, for the longest time I was trying to solve the challenge by writing "num = nil". What doesn't make sense to me is, why does "nums[index]" work and not "num"? Don't they refer to the same thing?

Comment: `num` is a block-local variable, `nums` is the array. Modifying a local parameter is different than accessing a reference. As another example, say that the array was filled with objects. `num.some_property = 5` would modify the property of the array entry, `num = SomeNewObject.new` would just create a new object and not modify the array entry. Same thing would happen if you were calling a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68470054/replacing-the-value-of-an-element-in-an-array-without-creating-a-new-array/69516801#comment121007655_68470054) from [Dave Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992):

> `num` is a block-local variable, `nums` is the array. Modifying a local parameter is different than accessing a reference. As another example, say that the array was filled with objects. `num.some_property = 5` would modify the property of the array entry, `num = SomeNewObject.new` would just create a new object and not modify the array entry. Same thing would happen if you were calling a function.